# How to open a Higher Level Landsat image with ENVI 5.2?

Tags: landsat, envi

A mistake every time I try to open the .MTL archive. The error that appears says "File does not appear to be a valid TIFF file". The archive's size it's smaller than it should be. Is there's any plugin to open correctly the images?

Comment: Have you tried a different MTL file?

Answer (score 2):

[Landsat L1 product](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-level-1-standard-data-products) metadata is contained in [`.MTL` archive](https://landsat.usgs.gov/level-1-landsat-data-products-metadata), L1 level are Landsat products in DN or TOA reflectance. Higher Level Landsat Image in [BOA reflectance](https://landsat.usgs.gov/does-landsat-level-1-data-processing-include-atmospheric-correction) has another kind of metadata structure. The metada [is located in `.xml` archive](https://landsat.usgs.gov/higher-level-science-data-products-metadata).

Envi 5.2 open and stack data from `.MTL` metadata, but it hasn't support for `.xml` metadata structure. Is a blog of Harris Geospatial, there is a mention of a [plugin automatizing open and layer stacking from `.xml` file](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Learn/Blogs/Blog-Details/TabId/2716/ArtMID/10198/ArticleID/15405/Working-with-Landsat-Surface-Reflectance-High-Level-Data-Products-in-ENVI.aspx), but there isn't in extensions library from Harris Geospatial portal.

So you have three options:

1. Open and stack it manually.
2. Create an IDL script to do it.
3. Open `.xml` file in other software that supports that kind of metadata and export the multi-raster file.